# Powershell Show-Command help button behavior

Tags: powershell

I've created a powershell script with comment-based help and when I do `Show-Command .\MyScript.ps1` and click on "Help" button - the help is not shown:
[image]even though typing `Get-Help .\MyScript.s1` works just fine:[image].

- Is it some kind of limitation of `Show-Command` "Help" button and it doesn't work fine with comment-based help?
- How to make `Show-Command` "Help" button understand my script's help?

Comment: same behavior here, the help button seems to work only for modules, not for scripts

Comment: Maybe a scope issue? I guess you could try this: go to your console, `$x = 'test'`, edit your help button to print `$x`, then do `show-command` and see if the button prints `test`.

Comment: @JacobColvin could you please explain what do you mean by "edit help button"? this button is handled by powershell runtime, so there's no way to alter it's behavior. Or did I get you incorrectly?

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize exactly what you were doing. But the item itself that is showing you what is in/out of scope isn't really important.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't seem to store the comment in your session. You can source the script and then show-command on the function, that seems to work. But it really doesn't seem to be a scope issue, everything else works fine for me besides the help comment.